# Wordpress Databases

Tags: mysql, database

i want to access wordpress databases in cpanel.I have access to them as in phpmyadmin but i want to add/remove data from them without actually deleting or adding in cpnael.I read about wpd class that talks to wordpress db.What is the best approach of doing this.
Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using WordPress, on any file that processes PHP, you can use regular MySQL queries.

```
    function create_table() { 
       global $wpdb;
       $table = $wpdb->prefix . "some_table_name";
       $charset_coll = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
       $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table ( id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       first_name varchar(50) DEFAULT
   ); $charset_collate;"

         }
```

That's for a plugin. You  might need to do things like check for the existence of the table, first, etc. before actually using that. Adjust to suit your needs.